# Photo has an extension that does not match its contents, rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

i have a problem with using paperclip. when i resart my rails server i can once upload a image using paperclip(success), but when i try to upload another image i'm always getting the error message: "Photo has an extension that does not match its contents".
for file validation i use:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
```

i use ruby 2.0 and rails 4.1.1 and the file i try to upload is ofc an image.
can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

thanks, felix.

Comment: Does commenting out the validation make the problem go away? What is the file type and extension of the 2nd image?

Comment: its the same image, that's why i can't figure out where the problem is. and it's a simple .jpg-file

Comment: How about my first question? Does commenting out the call to `validates_attachment_content_type` make the error go away? I only ask to help you narrow it down to that line.

Comment: no, when i uncomment this line an error occur, because paperclip needs that validation since version 4 i thought.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation failed: Upload file has an extension that does not match its contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629888/validation-failed-upload-file-has-an-extension-that-does-not-match-its-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this `validates_attachment_content_type :asset, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/`

It should work