# Paperclip ruby gem do not allow m3u8 or m3u extension (HTTP Live Streaming playlist (application/vnd.apple.mpegurl))

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am trying to upload file with extension m3u8 through paperclip and have content type `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`. Paperclip save content type as a `text/plain` in database.

I have validate as below.

```
 validates_attachment_content_type :media,
                                    :content_type => ['application/vnd.apple.mpegurl', 'text/plain']
```

But it gives validation error like "file has an extension that does not match its contents"

Could you please help to fix how I can allow m3u8 extension to upload ?

Thanks in advance, Nitin

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629888/validation-failed-upload-file-has-an-extension-that-does-not-match-its-contents

Comment: Yes right. but Bypass the file check by setting the file type totally from it's file extension is not working in my case....
.m3u8 gives mime-type 'text/plain'