# Rails paperclip attachment validation failure with .ogg format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

this is my first post on stackoverflow. I'm developing a rails app which require a song model that has an .ogg audio file attached by paperclip. I'm using .ogg format due to some browsers audio formats restrictions.

Unfortunately, when creating a new song object, it seems to fail all format validations, preventing the uploading of the audio file.

I've tried several format descriptions, such as 'audio/ogg', 'audio,oga', video/ogg'... But none seems to work. Uploading .mp3 files works fine, but I need to use .ogg due to reasons explained above.

I use paperclip to upload image files in other models of the app and it works fine, so it seems that I'm missing something... Thanks in advance for all your help!

**The model, song.rb:**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :lyrics, :track_order, :music_file, :url

  has_attached_file :music_file, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :name, :lyrics, :track_order, :record_id
  validates_attachment_presence :music_file
  validates_attachment_content_type :music_file, :content_type => ['audio/ogg', 'video/ogg']

  belongs_to :record

  default_scope order('track_order ASC')

  before_validation :set_file_url

  private

  def set_file_url
    self.url = music_file.url
  end

end
```

**The error I get:**

```
ArgumentError (uncaught throw #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000560df60 @base=#<Song id: 12, name: "Las Horas", lyrics: "Letra aquí", track_order: 1, record_id: 2, created_at: "2014-09-30 14:06:05", updated_at: "2014-09-30 15:27:25", music_file_file_name: "lshoras.ogg", music_file_content_type: "video/ogg", music_file_file_size: 3220214, music_file_updated_at: "2014-10-01 08:59:56", url: "/system/songs/music_files/000/000/012/original/lsho...">, @messages={:music_file=>["has an extension that does not match its contents"], :name=>[], :lyrics=>[], :track_order=>[]}>):
  app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:33:in `throw'
  app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:33:in `update'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your ogg file has a wrong mime, checking [this](http://wiki.xiph.org/MIME_Types_and_File_Extensions), you can see that ogg files should have `audio/ogg` but your's seem to have `video/ogg` (ogv). You can check it with:

```
file -b --mime lshoras.ogg
```

If this doesn't solve your problem you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629888/validation-failed-upload-file-has-an-extension-that-does-not-match-its-contents) to disable or modify the validation:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { ogg: 'application/ogg' }
```

Comment: The result of the checking:
`application/ogg; charset=binary`

Tryed to add 
`:content_type => ['application/ogg', 'audio/ogg', 'video/ogg']` but keeps failing.

Also tryed to upload different ogg files from other sources, still failing the validation.

Comment: what about doing `Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { ogg: 'application/ogg' }` ?