# getting validation error when trying to attach image via paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I am trying to attach an image via paperclip. But not working. The default image is showing fine. But I cant upload images using the browse option. Here is the error am getting.

**"1 error prohibited this listing from being saved: Image has an extension that does not match its contents"**

I have added the validation in model aswell. Here is mylistings.rb which is in models.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
end
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629888/validation-failed-upload-file-has-an-extension-that-does-not-match-its-contents)

Answer (score 0):

you can use content type validation like this also:

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

end